# Use AMPscript to calculate an Expiration date and validity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to check the syntax of the AMPscript below because I cannot preview and test email,... I have an other issue which I don't understand because I could send emails previously and I don't change anything on the Admin settings... I have to troubleshoot, but I guess it's because of the AMPscript is false? But the message is not for this reason.

```
%%[
var @currentSystemDateTime, @ExpirationDate, @oneMonthDate, @validity

set @currentSystemDateTime = Now(1)
set @currentSystemDateTime = "14/02/2019"
set @ExpirationDate = AttributeValue "ExpirationDate"
set @oneMonthDate = dateadd(@ExpirationDate,1,"MM")
set @validity = dateadd(@currentSystemDateTime,@oneMonthDate)


]%%
<br>currentSystemDateTime: %%=v(@currentSystemDateTime)=%%
<br>ExpirationDate: %%=v(@ExpirationDate)=%%
<br>validity: %%=v(@validity)=%%
```

**(ExpirationDate (Number) : attribute of my data extension))**

Thanks a lot for your help!

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `ExpirationDate` in your sending Data Extension?

Comment: You're missing parentheses around your AttributeValue function argument.

Comment: Also, [DateAdd()](https://ampscript.guide/book/dateadd/) requires 3 arguments.  The assignment for `@validity` only has two.

Comment: @pauline - You need to ask support to remove Can-Spam validation on your account - and remove the default footer :-)